# ReactJS Warning Component Change Uncontrolled Hidden Field to Controlled

Tags: reactjs

I have a hidden field that contains a csrf token that has its value set after a `node-fetch` successfully returns a JSON object and I'm not sure why I would receive the following warning based on my current setup. To my knowledge this warning should be thrown if using either the controlled or uncontrolled methods to update and set an input field, but I feel like simply setting a prop as a value does not fit the criteria I read in the documentation.

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type hidden to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Located at:

```
in input (created by ActivityFeedSearchForm)
    in form (created by ActivityFeedSearchForm)
    in div (created by ActivityFeedSearchForm)
    in div (created by ActivityFeedSearchForm)
    in div (created by ActivityFeedSearchForm)
    in ActivityFeedSearchForm (created by ActivityFeed)
    in div (created by ActivityFeed)
    in ActivityFeed
```

Now here is my code from Parent to child, where the warning is thrown:

ActivityFeed:

```
export default class ActivityFeed extends React.Component{

    export default class ActivityFeed extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || { test: [] };
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch(`${API_ROOT}` + '/api' + window.location.search, { compress: false })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ 
                    ...
                    csrf: data.csrfToken, 
                    ...
                });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {  
            return (
                <div>
                    <Navigation notifications={this.state.notifications}/>
                    <ActivityFeedSearchForm csrf={this.state.csrf} ... />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

ActivityFeedSearchForm:

```
//Activity Feed - Search Form
export default class ActivityFeedSearchForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
        var clearFilters;
        if(this.typeQuery || this.props.categoryQuery || this.props.departmentQuery || this.props.teamQuery || this.props.startDateQuery || this.props.endDateQuery || this.props.typeQuery){
            clearFilters = <a href="/app" id="clear-filter">Clear</a>;
        }

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="feed-search-form col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div clas="row">
                        <form action="/app" method="post" className="feed-filter-fields">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>
                            ...
                            <div className="col-md-1 feed-filter-section filter-button-container">
                                <button type="submit" id="feed-filter-submit">Filter</button>
                                {clearFilters}
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, decide if you want this form element to be **controlled** (value set programmatically from React state and/or JS logic) or **uncontrolled** (value set by the user input).

### If you want a controlled input

Very likely, since it's a hidden input! It looks like you want this input to be **controlled**, but, when React sees `undefined` passed to its `value` prop, that makes React think you want it to be uncontrolled.

To fix that, pass an empty string `''` or `0` when you want to tell React that this input's value is a falsy one, not `undefined` (which will cause this warning) or `null` (which will cause another warning). Ideally you would change your application logic to ensure that either `''` or `0` is always set in the null condition.

Or... the quick an dirty solution is something like this:

`<input value={yourValue || ''} />`

### If you want an uncontrolled input

(Very unlikely for a hidden input...)

Don't set a `value` prop, instead, set a `defaultValue` prop.

If you want a pseudo-controlled input where what is displayed in the input changes when some value variable changes, but also, users can edit it too, you could try something like this, where the element's key changes when the passed-in value, making React treat it like a new replacement element:

```
<input defaultValue={yourValue} key={`some-key-${yourValue}`} />
```

...but this will also cause the input to lose focus any time the defaultValue changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found the issue is where you define `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>`.

Your `csrf` is probably *undefined* first (and the input is uncontrolled) then you change it to a controlled ones by setting a value.

If you want to keep it uncontrolled, just put a default props value using `defaultProps`:

```
ActivityFeedSearchForm.defaultProps = {
  csrf: null,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I added your code outside of `export default class ActivityFeedSearchForm extends React.Component`, but I still see the error. Is there another adjustment I should make?

Comment: I discovered that the better method is `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf ? this.props.csrf : ""}/>` This removed the warning

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the previous answer, i refer you to the official documentation :https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
You need to check if there is async event who init the value of your input value. If one time on the lifecyle the value is undefined, you have the error message `A component is changing an uncontrolled input etc...`